# How to add http header to requests made by OSMDroid?

Tags: android, http-headers, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have my client's open street map tile server, which identificates client by checking cookie header sent with request. Here is a format:

Header:

```
Cookie: my_clients_company_cookie=0hPRvPfAK65TLASejXTtb6xjsRcH0D7t
```

Request:

```
https://fleet.my_clients_company.com/tile?z=10&x=610&y=510
```

Here is TileSource config I use:

```
val tileSource: ITileSource
    get() = object : OnlineTileSourceBase(
        "My Client's Company", // name
        3, // min zoom 
        18, // max zoom
        512, // tile size
        ".png",
        arrayOf("https://fleet.my_clients_company.com/tile")
    ) {

        override fun getTileURLString(pMapTileIndex: Long): String =
            "$baseUrl?z=${MapTileIndex.getZoom(pMapTileIndex)}&x=${MapTileIndex.getX(pMapTileIndex)}&y=${MapTileIndex.getY(pMapTileIndex)}"

    }
```

Without sending header, I get 401 Unauthorized error response. I haven't find a way to set headers.  Is it possible without forking library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not possible to supply the cookie value as a normal GET parameter by appending to the URL (did you try this?), I believe you have to implement your own Tile Source.

You can have a look at the [BingMapTileSource](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/abbd81948f6ab0dc6563d6706799a664c1c4d32a/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/bing/BingMapTileSource.java#L239) which sets a UserAgent header, similarly you could set a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Alex's answer is correct. To make it more clear, there is a possibility to set headers, using `Configuration` class. To set Cookie header, I need to add entry to the map of http request properties:

```
Configuration.getInstance().additionalHttpRequestProperties["Cookie"] = "my authorization cookie"
```

Comment: This member is now `private` it seems: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/discussions/1961